# How to inspect/debug an Instagram Basic Display API token

Tags: facebook, instagram

When linking with the Instagram Basic Display, our app asks for the `user_profile` and `user_media` scopes. When linking, the user can de-select the `user_media` scope, which defeats the purpose of linking with our app.

I'd like to validate that the user has granted the `user_media` permissions, but can't figure out a good way to do it.

The [Facebook Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/) is able to display the scopes that were granted when I paste in an IG Basic token.

I've tried using the `/debug_token` [endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/debug_token/) from the Graph API. It lets me debug Facebook and IG Graph tokens, but not IG Basic:

```
GET /debug_token?input_token=<token-to-debug>&access_token=<app-access-token>
```

The "app-access-token" I'm supplying is my Instagram Basic Display app's ID and secret combined together like this: `app-id|app-secret`

When I do this I get an error saying:

> Error validating application. Cannot get application info due to a system error.

The only thing I can think of doing is to try accessing the user's IG media and detecting if it fails w/a permissions error. I'd like to avoid doing this if there is a better way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up verifying this with an api request that tries to fetch the last media posted by the user:

(Ruby)

```
  def validate_permissions
    params = { access_token: token, fields: ['id'], limit: 1 }
    get('https://graph.instagram.com/me/media', params)
  end
```

The `get` method in this class has an error handler for when the HTTP status >= 400. In the error handler, if the HTTP status is a `403` and the error has a "code" of `190` then we can conclude the user has not granted the permission.

The error message in this scenario is:

> Application does not have permission for this action (access user media)